# MySql : How to update column of table by checking for multiple fields in where clause?

Tags: mysql

I tried this way

```
update message set status='Accepted' where tid=' ' and ltime=' ' and ldate=' ';
```

But it shows `error` in syntax.

My row is uniquely identified through these three fields.

Comment: Please show the complete error message, this query should work. What types are tid ltime ldate?

Comment: What datatype are your columns tid, ltime and ldate?

Answer (score 0):

Since **status** is a `reserved` `keyword`

Try like this

```
update message 
set `status`='Accepted' 
where tid=' ' and ltime=' ' and ldate=' ';
```

[Keywords and Reserved Words in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)